Krb5LoginModule accepts ANY password for a valid user
Our jaas.config reads simply:
Our_Kerberos {
        com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule REQUIRED
                useTicketCache=false
                refreshKrb5Config=true;
};

The earlier testing verified, that bad passwords don't work, and correct ones do -- as one'd expect.
However, we just noticed, that after a user logs in with a correct password, he -- or anyone else, who knows his login name -- can also login with a wrong password... Until the app is restarted...
What are we doing wrong here? Using JDK-11.0.22 on RedHat-7. The Kerberos servers are Active Directory...
During that first -- unsuccessful -- attempt to use the wrong password, we see the following log-entries on the server:
2024-04-17 14:49:32,175 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO - >>> KdcAccessibility: remove wt00.prod.example.net.:88
2024-04-17 14:49:32,175 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO - >>> KDCRep: init() encoding tag is 126 req type is 11
2024-04-17 14:49:32,175 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO - >>>KRBError:
2024-04-17 14:49:32,175 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO -          sTime is Wed Apr 17 14:49:32 EDT 2024 1713379772000
2024-04-17 14:49:32,175 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO -          suSec is 954940
2024-04-17 14:49:32,175 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO -          error code is 25
2024-04-17 14:49:32,175 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO -          error Message is Additional pre-authentication required
2024-04-17 14:49:32,175 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO -          sname is krbtgt/PROD.EXAMPLE.NET@PROD.EXAMPLE.NET
2024-04-17 14:49:32,175 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO -          eData provided.
2024-04-17 14:49:32,175 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO -          msgType is 30
2024-04-17 14:49:32,175 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO - >>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 19
         PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 18, salt = PROD.EXAMPLE.NETa....b, s2kparams = null

2024-04-17 14:49:32,175 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO - >>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 2
         PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP
2024-04-17 14:49:32,176 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO - >>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 16

2024-04-17 14:49:32,176 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO - >>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 15

2024-04-17 14:49:32,176 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO - KrbAsReqBuilder: PREAUTH FAILED/REQ, re-send AS-REQ

But later, after one successful login, the log-entries for each subsequent one are much shorter:
2024-04-17 14:49:53,683 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO - Java config name: null
2024-04-17 14:49:53,683 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO - Native config name: /etc/krb5.conf
2024-04-17 14:49:53,684 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO - Loading krb5 profile at /etc/krb5.conf
2024-04-17 14:49:53,684 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO - Loaded from native config
2024-04-17 14:49:53,684 [Thread-24 - Worker-1] console : INFO - >>> KdcAccessibility: reset

How do we make it validate the supplied credentials every time?

can also login with a wrong password no, more likely what is happening is the logon is failing. The client still has a valid token though.

No, the client is completely new process each time -- tested from a different computer even. But, until the server-process is restarted, it will allow the same username through with any password :(

Obviously this is not Active Directory or whatever authentication repository the application is hitting. And, given that the application is presented with credentials, Kerberos has been rendered all but irrelevant.

It may, indeed, be an application-bug -- and we've reached out to the vendor already. But is our jaas.config valid -- and supposed to work?

Of course it's a bug. And it doesn't have any logging or tools to facilitate investigation?
